# How does Parallel tempering work for optimisation procedures?

Tags: simulations, computational-physics

Markov Chain Monte Carlo procedures can be used in global optimisation procedures. [Parallel tempering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_tempering) is a particular type of stochastic sampling, but how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are not asking about how parallel tempering works as an algorithm for sampling from probability distributions, but that you are in fact interested in finding the global minimum of a target function $E(x)$. If that's not the case, please clarify what exactly you didn't understand from the Wikipedia page you linked and I'll be happy to edit my answer.

I never used parallel tempering explicitly for optimization, but my guess would be that you have to transform $E(x)$ into a probability density $p(x)$ via, e.g., $p(x)\propto\exp(-E(x))$, such that the modes of $p(x)$ correspond to the local and global minima of $E(x)$. Then you sample from $p(x)$ using parallel tempering and some local sampling algorithm like a basic Random Walk [Metropolis-Hastings MCMC sampler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) with a simple proposal density or [Hamiltonian Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_Monte_Carlo) and, after you're sort of sure the whole thing converged, define as the approximate global minimum $x_0$ of $E(x)$ the sample with the highest probability $p(x_0)$. Note that $p(x)$ does not have to be normalized.

Comment: Glad I could help! Sure, let me know when you have further questions; either here in the comments or, if they're somewhat detached from my answer or your original question, consider asking a new question here on physics or on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com, where it perhaps may be more appropriate.